# Isolating the Inheritance into a Function

Tags: javascript

http://jsbin.com/ifoguf/14/edit#javascript

I attempted Isolating the Inheritance Part into a Function, but when I create the object nothings is alerted, no errors are returned, so I'm stumped how to debug, and for a solution.

```
function Shape(){}
// augment prototype
Shape.prototype.name = 'shape';
Shape.prototype.toString = function() {return this.name;};

function TwoDShape(){}


// augment prototype
TwoDShape.prototype.name = '2D shape';



function Triangle(side, height) {
this.side = side;
this.height = height;
}


// augment prototype
Triangle.prototype.name = 'Triangle';
Triangle.prototype.getArea = function(){return this.side * this.height / 2;};




var myTriangle = new Triangle(5, 10);

function extend(Child, Parent) {
var F = function(){};
F.prototype = Parent.prototype;
Child.prototype = new F();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
Child.uber = Parent.prototype;
}


extend(TwoDShape, Shape);
extend(Triangle, TwoDShape);


var myTriangle = new Triangle(5, 10);


alert(myTriangle.getArea());

alert(myTriangle.toString());

var s = new Shape();
alert(s.name);
```

TIA

Comment: Please paste code here so that the context of the question is not lost when the link expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seemed a bit complex. See a simpler [example](http://jsfiddle.net/eTX2V/) (remember to switch on a debugging tool to see log messages).

It's worth noting that inheritance in JavaScript works by following prototype chains. That means every object holds a reference to a prototype object. This prototype object is just any ordinary object, too. The key is is that whenever a property (or function) is not found within an object, its prototype object is checked. This follows the prototype links until either a value was found or no prototypes are left over.

The prototype link is stored within an object whenever an object is created and points to the object as specified in the `prototype` property of the object's constructor function. You can inspect the prototype in Firefox by checking an object's [`__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

In the linked example, there are 3 constructors:

- Shape
- Triangle
- createPrototype (helper to get an empty object with defined prototype link)

In the linked example, there are 2 prototype objects:

- Shape.prototype (contains shared properties for shapes)
- Triangle.prototype (contains shared properties for triangles)

First a shape is created by calling `new Shape()`. This creates a new object since `new` is written in front of the function named `Shape`. The prototype link of the object (`__proto__` in Firefox) points to `Shape.prototype` because this property of the constructor function gives the prototype link's target. The link is set on object instantiation.

As a result whenever you try to access a property of the `shape` the property is retrieved as follows. First, `shape` is searched for the property. If it's there, use it. If not, the prototype object `shape.__proto__` is retrieved which refers to the same object as `Shape.prototype`. Now, the prototype object is searched for the property.

For the case of triangle the thing is a bit more complex because multiple prototype links are involved. The important thing is that we need to create an empty object to hold the triangles' shared properties which also needs to have its prototype link set to point to `Shape.prototype`. This makes shape's prototype the fallback of triangle's prototype.
It is archived by the anonymous function that includes `createPrototype`. It needs to be included because every invocation of the anonymous function needs to manipulate the `prototype` property of a constructor function (called `createPrototype` in our case). After the empty prototype object with the prototype chain is created, it is instantly returned and assigned to `Triangle.prototype`. After that any object created by `new Triangle()` has the desired prototype chain.

Once this is set, we can add all shared properties of triangles into the `Triangle.prototype` object that was just created. This is shown by overriding `paint` and by adding `getArea`. Note this overriding actually works because the `paint` function for triangles is found earlier than the `paint` method for shapes and the first found reference/property is used.

To summarize, all property accesses on objects use prototype chains for fallbacks. In our case the chain for `shape` is `shape`→`Shape.prototype` and the one for `triangle` is `triangle`→`Triangle.prototype`→`Shape.prototype`.

*You might want to assign a name to the anonymous function (that includes `createPrototype`) to have a tool for created object hierarchies. This is shown in the [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/eTX2V/3/) and ends up with the following helper:*

```
function makePrototype(parent){
    // We need a new object whose prototype link points to parent.prototype
    function createPrototype(){
    }
    createPrototype.prototype = parent.prototype;
    return new createPrototype();
}
```